# Custom tab completion in python argparse

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, argparse, tab-completion

How to get shell tab completion cooperating with `argparse` in a Python script?

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse

def main(**args):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('positional', choices=['spam', 'eggs'])
    parser.add_argument('--optional', choices=['foo1', 'foo2', 'bar'])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

With an executable flag set on the .py file, the expected results should be something like:

```bash
$ ./example.py sp<tab>             
   ->  completes to "./example.py spam"
$ ./example.py --op<tab> 
   ->  completes to "./example.py --optional"
$ ./example.py --optional b<tab>
   ->  completes to "./example.py --optional bar"
$ ./example.py --optional f<tab>   
   ->  completes to "./example.py --optional foo"
       and, additionally, prints  "foo1  foo2"  choices on stdout on a new line
```

Comment: This has a little background information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568611/how-does-argparse-and-the-deprecated-optparse-respond-to-tab-keypress-after

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Have a look at [argcomplete](https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/) by Andrey Kislyuk.

Install it with:

```
pip install argcomplete
```

Import the module and add one line in your source before calling `parser.parse_args()`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse as ap
import argcomplete

def main(**args):
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('positional', choices=['spam', 'eggs'])
  parser.add_argument('--optional', choices=['foo1', 'foo2', 'bar'])
  argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  main(**vars(args))
```

and to make sure that bash knows about this script, you use

```
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete your_script)"
```

you should put that line in your `~/.bashrc` or follow argcomplete's docs and activate 'global' completion.

After that you completion works as requested.

The way this works is that the eval line creates a function `_python_argcomplete` which is registered using `complete`. (Run `register-python-argcomplete your_script` to just have a look at what gets eval-ed into bash). The autocomplete function looks for environment variables set by the bash completion mechanism to see if it needs to act. If it acts, it exits the program. If it doesn't act, this is a normal call to the program that function does nothing and the normal flow of the program continues.

Comment: If you enable "global completion", you need to place the comment `# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK` at the beginning of the Python file (e.g., as the second line, right after the `#!/usr/bin/env python`), or the autocompletion will not work. I suggest to edit the code in the answer, adding the aforementioned comment line.

Comment: @AlbertoPettarin I explicitly did not mention global completion, as it requires additional set up and incurs a general performance hit on tab completion (because of opening multiple files searching for a potential `PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK`. The global tab completion and the requirements are mentioned in the link in the article (and now in your comment), that is good enough.

Comment: There's also `activate-global-python-argcomplete` available (I think this may be newish, as I don't recall it being there last time I looked).

Comment: I have a big project, so if this will help me to autogenerate bash completion script, or in anyway so that I'don't have to maintain the script for command completion manually?

Comment: @shiminsh That is its intention, but it depends a bit whether this will work for you. argcomplete starts the application to dynamically generate the completion information and that can take time depending on how your application is structured. For me the delay this caused got annoying enough to not use argcomplete in most of my projects. But if you already use `argparse` adding argcomplete to try it  out is really little work.

Comment: Does this still work if you try to use `python your_script`? It seems to only work for me if I `chmod +x ./your_script` and then try to run it with `./your_script`. If this is expected behaviour, I think this answer should mention this.

Comment: Updated link for argcomplete documentation: https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/

Comment: Should I test is using ` ./minimal.py [TAB]`?

Comment: @alper I think that depends on your shell and/or shell settings. I am currently not using argcomplete, so I cannot help much more

Comment: I hoped PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK would work for me, because overhead is okay in my application. Weirdly, it works to complete "filename.py" when I hit tab after `python filena`, but not after `python -i filena`. I guess somehow argparse (which is looking for "-i") is interfereing with the global flag. So I had to go with the answer that relies on `import argcomplete`. Edit -- actualy this weirdly only works to autocomplete directories, not filenames

Comment: In `zsh` when I press `TAB` this solution shows additional arguments: `ALTERNATE_EDITOR              LESS_TERMCAP_ue
_ARGCOMPLETE                  LESS_TERMCAP_us _ARGCOMPLETE_COMP_WORDBREAKS  LOGNAME
_ARGCOMPLETE_SUPPRESS_SPACE   LS_COLORS
BAT_PAGER                     LSCOLORS
BROWNIE_LIB                   LSP_USE_PLISTS
CLICOLOR                      MANPAGER
COLUMNS                       NVM_BIN
COMP_CWORD                    NVM_CD_FLAGS
COMP_LINE                     NVM_DIR
COMP_POINT                    NVM_INC
FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS               PS1` ... is it normal?

Answer (score 5):

For auto-complete to work you need a bash function to generate the possible options, and then you need to run `complete -F <function_name> <program_name>`

The best way of doing this is to have the program generate the completion function based on it's own parsing algorithm to avoid duplication. However, at a quick glance on argparse, I could not find a way to access it's internal structure, but I suggest you look for it.

Here is a bash function that will do for the above program:

```
function _example_auto() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    case "$prev" in
    --optional ) 
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "foo1 foo2 bar" -- $cur) )
        return 0
        ;;
    *)
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "--optional spam eggs" -- $cur) )
        return 0
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: This program is just an example. It's possible to list all options for certain program, but not for library. Something like `optcomplete` equivalent for `argparse` will do the job, but other (including partial) solutions are welcome too.