# Tab autocomplete when calling filename as arg for python script?

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete

I wrote one python file, which accepts filename as args into, it works fine, but I want to make autocomplete for that arg as bash-autocomplete.

```
python my_script.py some_script.py
```

Arg must be a filename from specific folder(there are 30+ files in, which I may use as arg). Path to folder doesn't change. I've read about bash autocompletes, but didn't find a case for watching a folder with files.
How to implement autocomplete with in-folder filenames?

Comment: This might get your interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597466/custom-tab-completion-in-python-argparse

Comment: @Shinratensei, good solution