# Auto complete ArgumentParser in Python

Tags: python, autocomplete, argparse

I have a custom Python module installed that I want to modify so that it provides an auto-complete function similar to other bash programs so that when the `Tab` key is pressed a list of variables is printed out or a value is placed in the terminal. I'm not really running in a traditional sense but rather typing the name of the module which is aliased to run a conda environment yada yada. Is

there anyway to get argparse answer with parameter values? For example: after typing `python3 ./module rollback -c` and pressing `tab` could I list out some strings?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')

rollback = subparsers.add_parser('rollback', help='Rollback to previous commit')
rollback.add_argument('-c', '--commit', dest='incomingCommitHash', default=None, type=str, required=False, help='Commit to deploy')
```

Comment: `python3 ./module rollback -h` is the only builtin help method.  There is some sort of third party completer that can with `argparse` but I haven't used it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597466/custom-tab-completion-in-python-argparse.  https://pypi.org/project/argcomplete/