# Have bash auto complete functions from python script

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python argparse and bash completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387924/python-argparse-and-bash-completion)

In a bash prompt (like on a Ubuntu system) if you type `service` and then tab a few times you would get a list of all the services available.

Is there a way to do the same with a python script? So if you had a script called music that looked like this:

```
def dumbstuff():
    #plays pop music...

def rockingstuff():
    #Plays music that will scare your mother...
```

And on the command line you type `music` with a few tabs I would like to see outputted:

```
dumbstuff
rockingstuff
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could go about this two way.  The first methodology would be to create a bash completion script and reference it in your .bashrc file.  You can see and example of this here:[An Introduction to Programmable Completion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html).

The other way you could go is to use the [optcomplete](http://furius.ca/optcomplete/) library for python.  You have to include it as part of your script.

Which methodology you choose depends on whether this application is just for personal use or distribution.