# Is there a way to get argparse options work with tab-expansion?

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, argparse

I have a python script that takes in several files as required arguments, which I parse with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--imgtfile", required=True, help="IMGT file")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--fastqfile", required=True, help="FASTQ file")
parser.add_argument("-g", "--gene", required=True, help="Gene to extract")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--outfile", help="name of the output file")
# ... more arguments
argcomplete.autocomplete(parser) # <-- this doesn't help
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The issue is that the files have pretty long and annoying names. Shell tab expansion works great if the arguments are positional (i.e. no flags) but if I have flags the tab expansion doesn't work anymore. On the other hand I'd like to keep the flags to not hardcode the order of arguments.

I have looked into [`argcomplete`](https://argcomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) but can't really get it to work the way I like. It seems like I either need the `choices` option in `add_argument`, and/or fiddle with bash to enable global completion.

Since I am working remotely on a server, I'm a bit conservative about this. Seems to me as if there should be a simpler way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Python argparse and bash completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387924/python-argparse-and-bash-completion)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks. It's related yes, but doesn't provide a useful answer, as far as I can tell

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify why `argcomplete` does not work for you

Comment: @Chris_Rands the way it requires me to fiddle with system settings. I am generally not too keen on randomly running scripts that I have not written, on a server I am responsible for