# Split a string with multiple delimiters, and keep *some* of the delimiters, but not all

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string that can look something like this:

```
1. "foo bar"
2. "foo bar foo:bar"
3. "foo bar "
4. "foo bar      "
5. "foo bar foo:bar:baz"
```

I want to split this string so that it would end up with the following results:

```
1. ['foo', 'bar']
2. ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', ':', 'bar']
3. / 4. ['foo', 'bar', '']
5. ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', ':', 'bar', ':', 'baz']
```

In other words, following these rules:

1. Split the string on every occurrence of a space.

   a. If there are one or more spaces at the end of a string, add one empty string to the split list

   b. Any spaces before the last non-space character in a string should be consumed, and not add to the split list.
2. Split the string on every occurrence of a colon, and do *not* consume the colon.

The XY problem is this, in case it's relevant:

I want to mimic Bash tab-completion behaviour. When you type a command into a Bash interpreter, it will split the command into an array `COMP_WORDS`, and it will follow the above rules - splitting the words based on spaces and colons, with colons placed into their own array element, and spaces ignored unless they're at the end of a string. I want to recreate this behaviour in Python, given a string that looks like a command that a user would type.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) about splitting a string and keeping the separators using `re.split`. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python) about splitting using multiple delimiters. But my use case is more complicated, and neither question seems to cover it. I tried the following to at least split on spaces and colons:

```
print(re.split('(:)|(?: )', splitstr))
```

But even that doesn't work. When `splitstr` is "foo bar foo:bar" returns this:

```
['foo', None, 'bar', None, 'foo', ':', 'bar']
```

Any idea how this could be done in Python?

**EDIT:** My requirements weren't clear - I would want "foo bar   " (with any number of spaces at the end) to return the list `["foo", "bar", ""]` (with just one empty string at the end of the list.)

Comment: What if the string is `"foo bar      "` i.e. many spaces at the end?

Comment: maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387924/python-argparse-and-bash-completion

Comment: Maybe use `re.findall(r'[^:\s]+|:|(?<!\S)(?!\S)', text)`? See https://ideone.com/qttWe8

Comment: @Nick - then I still want to just get one space, as in `['foo', 'bar', '']`

Comment: @Lou that's not a space, it's an empty string at the end of that list

Comment: Could you just not filter out the `None` in a list comprehension?
`[x for x in result_from_re_split if x is not None]`

Comment: @buran - Thanks for the link. Argcomplete is okay, but not what I'm looking for in this situation (I've tried it, and it's just overkill).

Comment: @Nick - Of course you're right. My mistake. So what I want is an empty string at the end of the list if there are one or more spaces at the end of the string.

Comment: @GuillemB - That works too, good suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expressions for this task. String methods work just as well, and might be more readable.

```py
def split_comp(s: str) -> 'list[str]':
    trailing = s.endswith(' ')
    s = s.replace(':', ' : ')  # insert split marks before/after every colon
    parts = s.split()
    return parts if not trailing else [*parts, ' ']
```

This technique can be used for any delimiters – pick one delimiter to split on, then replace/pad those to remove/keep with it.

Comment: Could you explain what the syntax in the function definition is doing? I've never seen this before `(s: str) -> 'list[str]'`

Comment: @Lou Those are type annotations to show the expected input/output types. They serve as documentation and allow type checkers to verify code. See [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) and [What are variable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations).

Comment: Thanks, this solution works really neatly! The only other thing I don't get is why you have an asterisk before `parts`. It looks like an args and kwargs type thing, but I've only seen args used in function definitions like `def foo(*a, **b)` etc.

Comment: Ah never mind, I think I get it. The asterisk in `[*parts, ' ']` loads the elements of the list into a list, rather than the list itself - without the asterisk, you'd create a nested list. This is a really neat solution. I've accepted it because it's readable and concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `re.findall` approach here with:

```py
[^:\s]+|:|(?<=\S)(?=\s+$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XL9qzy/2/). *Details*:

- `[^:\s]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `:`
- `|` - or
- `:` - a colon
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\S)(?=\s+$)` - any empty string that is located between a non-whitespace and one or more whitespaces at the end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/b20bFD).

```py
import re
l = ['foo bar', 'foo bar foo:bar', 'foo bar ', 'foo     bar     ']
rx = re.compile(r'[^:\s]+|:|(?<=\S)(?=\s+$)')
for s in l:
    if s.rstrip() != s:
        s = s.rstrip() + " "
    print(f"'{s}'", '=>', rx.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
'foo bar' => ['foo', 'bar']
'foo bar foo:bar' => ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', ':', 'bar']
'foo bar ' => ['foo', 'bar', '']
'foo     bar ' => ['foo', 'bar', '']
```

Comment: @Nick As the question currently looks like it is fine.

Comment: @Nick You know no one reads comments, once the question is updated with clarifications, I will change the answer, it is easy to adjust to any extra requirements.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Lou Have  you tried the solution? It does what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry @Wiktor, life got in the way there. Your solution does what I want it to, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are shorter ways, but here is my suggestion:

```
def func(s):
    if s[-1]==' ':
        l=s.split()+['']
    else:
        l=s.split()
    def f(l):
        m=l.copy()
        res=[]
        for i in m:
            if i!=':' and ':' in i:
                temp=[i[:i.find(':')]]+[':']+[i[i.find(':')+1:]]
                res.extend(temp)
            else:
                res.append(i)
        return res
    while any(i!=':' and ':' in i for i in l):
        l=f(l)
    return l
```

Examples:

```
>>> func("foo bar")
['foo', 'bar']

>>> func("foo bar foo:bar")
['foo', 'bar', 'foo', ':', 'bar']

>>> func("foo bar ")
['foo', 'bar', '']

>>> func("foo bar      ")
['foo', 'bar', '']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tested it and it does work for the four cases you've shown, although unfortunately it doesn't work for contiguous strings with more than one colon in them, e.g.: `func("foo foo:bar:baz")` returns `['foo', 'foo', '', ':', '', 'bar', ':', 'baz']`

Comment: I did a change it should work now. The problem came from single ':' after the first split, which produced extra '' They are ignored now.